# NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getPassword

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, hadoop, nosuchmethoderror

I have been struggling with this `NoSuchMethodError` in a Spark project for a while now without getting anywhere. Currently, this project is running locally using SparkNLP 3.3.0 and Spark-Core/SparkMLLib 3.1.2, both with Scala 2.12.4. Hadoop 3.2.0 is pulled in as a transitive dependency via spark-core.

What I have tried so far:

- check that this method is indeed present by stepping through the code
- verify uniform Scala version across all dependencies
- verify that spark and hadoop versions are the same throughout (using maven dep tree and enforcer plug-in)
- manually remove other versions of Hadoop from local .m2 directory

The code is running from an executable JAR which pulls in other jars to the classpath that are provided at runtime. Java version is 1.8.0_282. Maven is version 3.6.3. OS is Big Sur, 11.6 (M1).

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getPassword(Ljava/lang/String;)[C
    at org.apache.spark.SSLOptions$.$anonfun$parse$8(SSLOptions.scala:188)
    at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.SSLOptions$.parse(SSLOptions.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.SecurityManager.<init>(SecurityManager.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:458)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2672)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$2(SparkSession.scala:945)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:939)
    [...]
    at com.mymainpackage.Main.main(Main.java:157)
```

Comment: Interestingly, when I change the module setup in IntelliJ to add the Scala 2.12.4 lib explicitly, the error changes to `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Product.$init$(Lscala/Product;)V`. And even more interesting: Removing the Scala lib again, does not revert to the original error

Comment: PPS: Updating to Scala 2.12.10 across the board doesn't help either. Both NoSuchMethodError's still present.

Comment: How do you run your code? via `spark-submit`?

Comment: No, it's all local.

Comment: For the record: Downgrading everything to Scala 2.11 doesn't help. Still getting `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getPassword(Ljava/lang/String;)[C`  (the other `NoSuchMethodError`, however is gone now)

Comment: Does a super simple Spark example work? Something like: https://github.com/jgperrin/net.jgp.books.spark.ch01/blob/master/src/main/java/net/jgp/books/spark/ch01/lab100_csv_to_dataframe/CsvToDataframeApp.java.

Comment: Recently I also had some issues with the various Java I had on my Mac (i9) using eclipse however. I ended up switching to Java 11 installed via brew.

Comment: @jgp Yes, this simple example works. Unfortunately, switching to a higher Java version is not an option, as the company's system is still based on Java 8.

Comment: Can you share more? Maybe put in a GitHub repo so I could clone it and see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally been able to figure this one out.
The root cause was that an older version of hadoop-core was being pulled in (1.2.1 instead of 2.6.5), which does in fact not have the `Configuration.getPassword()` method. I found this out after setting up a test project where the SparkContext was initialized correctly and then checking the source jars of the two Configuration classes in the two projects (using `Configuration.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()`).

After forcing version 2.6.5 using Maven's dependency management and after manually deleting the older 1.2.1 jar from the local Maven repo, it work fine.

The only thing that I still don't understand is why the `hadoop-core` was not showing up in the Maven dependency tree. Otherwise, I would have found sooner (probably).